Почему деконструкция вызывает ошибку?
Описание
Сделаю дополнения для стандартных модулей JS. К примеру:
/**
 * Clamps a value between a minimum and maximum.
 * @param {number} value The value to clamp.
 * @param {number} min The minimum value.
 * @param {number} max The maximum value.
 * @returns {number} The clamped value.
 */
Math.between = function (value, min, max) {
    return this.min(this.max(min, value), max);
};

Поскольку в коде будет часто использоваться эта функция получаю его отдельно с помощью деконструкции:
"use strict";

const { between } = Math;

between(30, 0, 10);

Выскакивает...

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'min')
at Math.between

Вопрос
Почему при деконструкции теряется ссылка на this?
Как исправить такую ошибку?

Надо просто использовать Math.min вместо this.min и всё будет хорошо

Не успел ответ написать. Можно прикрепить контекст к фукнции и уже ее присвоить для Math.between. function betweenfn () {}; Math.between = betweenfn.bind(Math) и this будет работать. Однако да, что this, что Math, наверное разницы нет

@SwaD это тоже может быть полезно. Иногда не очень удобно использовать сам объект вместо this

у Math все функции статические, внутри них не надо использовать this

@Grundy у меня такая ошибка была и в Event-ах. Вот тут к примеру, если invoker заменить на { change } и вызвать её опать же будет ошибка.

ну так правильно - если ты внутри функции используешь this - при получении отдельной ссылки на функцию - this теряется
